# MYSql create table throwing out error:1117 Too many columns

Tags: mysql, database

I have a scenario where I have to create a table with 1375 columns, among 1352 are of type VARCHAR(30) and 23 are of type TIMESTAMP.
ie : 40560 + 92 = 40652, which is less than the row size limit 65,535, mentioned in the following reference.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-count-limit.html#row-size-limits

Steps Tried:
  2. tried creating table with the option  ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET latin1, getting the error:1117
How to get out this issue?

I am using MYSQL8.0 version.

Comment: Are you sure you're on the right track? A single table with more than a thousand columns does not look really good. Additionally, what have you tried to resolve that problem? For example, the linked documentation clearly states a limit of 1017 columns per table for InnoDB

Comment: "How to get out this issue?"  Probably you start by designing your database tables properly.  Why would a table need 1375 columns???

Comment: Not to pile on to what was already said here... but this sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 0):

More than 1K columns does not sound reasonable, at least I can hardly envision a scenario where it would be desirable. I suspect that a different data modeling like [EAV](https://inviqa.com/blog/understanding-eav-data-model-and-when-use-it) or maybe using a Nosql DB like MongoDB could be a solution for you depending on your requirements.

Another solution would be to store the data across multiple tables with one to one relationships. You didn't give any details about your purpose but what you are trying to do sounds quite like a bad idea. But EAV has pitfalls too.

If you add more details to the question, maybe we can suggest better ideas.